# OneNote: missing share button

Tags: onenote

I used to have a share button in OneNote (Windows program, not the Windows Store app) but it is gone since I got a fresh Windows installation at work. It should be the same version or newer than before (version I now have is: Version 2308(Build 16731.20550), I don't know what I had before) I did manage to manually add it through custom ribbon, but it is not the same as before. Before I would get a share link in this form:

**NotebookName (Web view)**

How can I get this type of link again? The link I now get in the program, W10 app and through the site all give the regular website url.